# Script performace - script crashing the browser

Tags: javascript

I have a script that call a CGI to retrieve an XML, parses it, creates a table and show this table to the user. It is pretty simple..

My problem is when this XML is too big because it sometimes crashes the user's browser.
So I want your opinion about what I can improve in my function.

The function does that:

[1]. It parses the XML:

```
var xmlDoc = req.responseXML;
var rows = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('row');
var columns = rows[0].getElementsByTagName('column');
```

And after this I iterate over the columns to create my table.

[2]. I'm creating the table concatenating strings, like this (iterating over each column in each row):

```
 tableCells += '<td style="text-align:left">' + value + '</td>';
```

[3]. And to finish, I do this:

```
document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = resultsTable;
document.getElementById('results').style.display = "";
```

I checked how time takes these steps (profiling with chrome and firefox+firebug):

1. I removed all the concatenation and the [3]. The funcion took 0.5s.
2. I removed only the [3]. The function took 1.5s.
3. But if I add the [3] my function takes 15.5s (!!!).

What can I do to improve it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since innerHTML needs to be parsed by the browser you could try to speed things up by inserting DOM objects, so the there is no need of parsing a large string.

Instead of adding strings, you could use something like this in your table:

```
var resultTable = document.getElementById('...'), newRow, newCell;

// ... begin loop:
newRow = document.createElement('tr');
newCell = document.createElement('td');
newCell.textContent = "abc"; // use innerText in IE
newRow.appendChild(newCell);

resultTable.appendChild(newRow);
```

if you want to stick to strings, or if this does not give you a lot of improvement, you should optimize your HTML, for instance the style in here: `<td style="text-align:left">` can be eliminated by using CSS and should save you a lot of bytes which do not need to be parsed anymore. Add a CSS like this to acheive this: `td {text-align: left;}`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if may help but:

1. Create an element using javascript (Ex.:var el = document.createElement('span'))
2. Set the element innerHTML (Ex.: el.innerHTML = resultsTable)
3. appends it to the page

Comment: About Vash's solution, frequent DOM Tree modification cost more time and may launch lots of events.

Comment: Depending on the browser there are differences regarding this question, have a look here: http://andrew.hedges.name/experiments/innerhtml/

Comment: In fact. I would also use a different node, out of the document root, to add this nodes.